# Congratulations (again), Daniel Fischer!

Tags: discussion, celebration

No, this is not a belated post about the moderator election results.

Instead, I noticed that [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) has very recently topped 100K in reputation. And he accomplished that in one-year, six-months, while also contributing enormously through helpful comments on questions.

I think these feats are celebration-worthy, hence the post.

Congratulations, @Daniel Fischer ♦!

Comment: [Tadaa!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread/19136#19136)

Comment: We already have a congratulatory post for Daniel [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/19146/4583). Voting as duplicate.

Comment: Mine was first, @Ayman... nananana ;-) The post you refer to was not already there when I posted. My post was already here when that post was posted.

Comment: I understand. Let's consolidate these posts in one place. :)

Comment: He's catching you!