# Congratulations: the big thread!

Tags: discussion, celebration, big-list

Also known as the happiest place on the website! Use this thread to congratulate MSE users that you feel have reached a significant milestone on the website, or to congratulate the website itself, if you are so inclined. Frequent themes:

- A user reaches an integral multiple of 100,000 reputation points;
- The website reaches a number of questions/answers/users with a lot of zeroes at the end;
- *[to be expanded]...*

To reiterate, this thread should be a happy place. No mean comments directed at the congratulated people, please.

---

Some context: the [celebration](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/celebration) tag has been growing here on meta. Meanwhile, some people think these posts should be regrouped into a single thread, and these threads have become less popular than before. Recently, Alexander Gruber [made a suggestion that was well received](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/lets-make-one-big-happy-congratulations-thread): +38/-5. This is an attempt to implement this idea. The idea of editing the title with every new post was met with some resistance, but this can be implemented later if need be.

Meanwhile, the [History of MSE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7021/history-of-math-stackexchange) thread seems to be for *significant* milestones: there can only be one instance of a user reaching 100k *for the first time*. This prevents congratulating users on an individual basis.

Comment: As for why I went ahead and created the thread: there's sometimes a bit of inertia on this website. After a month and a half and without huge complaints against Alexander Gruber's idea, I thought it was time to try it out.

Comment: Voting on a *discussion* does not necessarily mean dis/agreement with any idea presented in OP. (It was likely still a good idea to create the thread.)

Comment: [In praise of Math.SE and its users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17403/in-praise-of-math-se-site-and-its-users).

Comment: What's with all the downvotes on answers in this thread?? What do people think they are accomplishing??

Comment: Has anyone compiled records of the "best" question posers, as opposed to the best question answerers? Would be more difficult to measure...

Comment: I'm only at 18k. Time to start Rep-Farming hard! [laughs]

Answer (score 47):

Congratulations to [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan?tab=activity) for being the first user to reach 1,000 (non-unique) badges, including 15 gold and 469 Nice Answers!

Answer (score 41):

Congratulations [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer) for getting into the 100k club. Your clear explanations and helpful hints combined with your patient mentoring does not go unnoticed in the math chatroom. Also [**this**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19425697#19425697) accomplishment has not been mentioned.

Comment: congratulations =) !

Answer (score 26):

User [Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did) has just hit **200K** rep today, and the number of 200K+ users on Math S.E. is now three.

Congratulations for your fantastic achievement Did! Your dedication, enthusiasm, and insight are really inspiring. You worked hard, you deserve it, and now you have got it! Please accept our congratulations on this wonderful recognition of your merits. *I wish you many years of great achievements! Keep up the good work!*

Answer (score 24):

Congratulations to [me](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8269/gerry-myerson), the first ever recipient of the highly-coveted [big-list bronze tag badge](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/510/big-list). This goes on my CV, for sure.

EDIT–––Even more congratulations to me, for achieving a reputation of exactly 123,456. Just enjoying it while it lasts.

MORE EDIT----I appear to be the first recipient, in the long history of math.stackexchange.com, of a "conjectures" tag badge, https://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/1145/conjectures Is this a new badge?

EVEN MORE EDIT ––– All three of my badge totals on main are, for the time being, multiples of $12$.

Comment: I have to thank all the little people who made my amazing achievement possible.

Comment: That's pretty crazy.

Comment: And as quickly as it arrived, it was gone again. You have my condolences.

Comment: It's probably just me, but I habitually misread those tag badges as concerning *non-commutative* wiki answers.

Comment: Out of idle curiosity, I did a histogram for the ones digit from the reputations of the $36$ highest-reputation people.  Listing the digts from $0$ to $9$, it's $(7,2,5,4,2,0,8,3,3,2)$.  Interesting that $6$ and $0$ are most common, while $5$ is absent.

Comment: IMHO, 123456 isn't that interesting as a number, wait until 196883 when you faithfully become a Monster ;-)

Comment: I'm looking forward to you hitting 234,567 soon enough!

Answer (score 21):

Congratulations to [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan) for reaching 200k reputation today!

Qiaochu is already a great contributor to the site in terms of giving answers, but let's not forget the fact that he has also served the site as one of the moderators for over 2.5 years.

Approximately a year ago, Qiaochu reached the milestone of 1,000 badges – he has now already 1,139 badges, including 518 Nice Answers.

Answer (score 20):

Congratulations to [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121/jack-daurizio) on reaching 100k reputation.

He has made several great answers with often inspiring, creative and elegant solutions.

Comment: Congrats on achieving this milestone for which you obviously worked so hard.  Your numerous insightful solutions have been a benefit to this site.

Comment: @RonGordon: I am just waiting for you to achieve the same goal ;)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Your answers are always pretty. You have a great gift for problem solving.

Answer (score 19):

Congratulations to [Henning Makholm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/14366/henning-makholm) on reaching $100$K on $5$ March $2015$, bringing the number of $100$K+ users to a full score; not bad for someone who describes ‘[r]eal mathematics’ as ‘more of hobby’!

I always enjoy reading your answers, and not just on account of my particular mathematical interests.

Comment: I was just going to post such a thread. Glad you beat me to it, @Brian.  More to the point, congratulations, Henning!! I *always* enjoy reading both your answers and your comments.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, @amWhy. It would have been more fun to clear the threshold back when it meant something, but eh.

Answer (score 18):

## Past congratulatory threads

This list was [compiled](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16882) by [Martin Sleziak](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297): all the credit goes to him.  I merely reformatted it.

> ### Reputation
>
> #### Reaching 100k
>
> (ordered by id)
>
> - [Congratulations, Arturo!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3558/congratulations-arturo)
> - [Congratulations, André!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6319/congratulations-andr%C3%A9)
> - [Congratulations, Qiaochu!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6515/congratulations-qiaochu)
> - [Congratulations, Brian M. Scott!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6648/congratulations-brian-m-scott)
> - [Congratulations, Did hits the 100K!!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9381/congratulations-did-hits-the-100k)
> - [Congratulations, Asaf!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10242/congratulations-asaf)
> - [Congratulations, Ross Millikan!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11240/congratulations-ross-millikan)
> - [Congratulations to Robert Israel!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11565/congratulations-to-robert-israel)
> - [Congratulations, amWhy hit 100k!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11756/congratulations-amwhy-hit-100k)
> - [Congratulations, Bill!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12317/congratulations-bill)
> - [Congratulations robjohn for getting into the 100k club.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13065/congratulations-robjohn-for-getting-into-the-100k-club)
> - [Congratulations, Gerry Myerson! Gerry Hits 100K Reputation!!!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13130/congratulations-gerry-myerson-gerry-hits-100k-reputation)
> - [Congratulations, Hagen von Eitzen! +100k !!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13813/congratulations-hagen-von-eitzen-100k)
> - [Congratulations, DonAntonio!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/congratulations-donantonio)
> - [Congratulations, joriki!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15038/congratulations-joriki)
> - [Congratulations, lab bhattacharjee!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16879/congratulations-lab-bhattacharjee)
> - [Congratulations (again), Daniel Fischer!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19134/congratulations-again-daniel-fischer)
>
> #### Reaching 200k
>
> (ordered by id)
>
> - [Congratulations to André Nicolas!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/congratulations-to-andr%C3%A9-nicolas)
> - [Congratulations to Brian M. Scott!! (200K edition)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11431/congratulations-to-brian-m-scott-200k-edition)
>
> #### Reaching 300k
>
> (ordered by id)
>
> - [Congratulations to André!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17439/congratulations-to-andre)
>
> ### Other achievements
>
> (ordered by id)
>
> - [Congratulations once again, André!!!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9380/congratulations-once-again-andr%C3%A9)
>     (on becoming the top user)
> - [Congrats and Thanks to Jonas Meyer!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16314/congrats-and-thanks-to-jonas-meyer)
>     (10k in bounties)
> - [Congratulations to Asaf](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9263/8348)
>     (visited math.SE for 1000 consecutive days)
>
> ### Other posts
>
> - [Congrats to Ross Millikan AND Davide Giraudo](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/congrats-to-ross-millikan-and-davide-giraudo)
>
>   - This posts contains also a feature request (suggestion for a new badge), so from this viewpoint it is somewhat different.

Answer (score 18):

Congratulations to [Ron Gordon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/53268/ron-gordon) for his glorious achievement: reputation over $100$K.

This man is a bless for us all: I learned so much by studying his answers in complex analysis, I will be grateful to him my whole life. And that is just a tiny part of his merits.

Comment: Jack, words fail.  Thank you.  We learn from each other - I have learned from you and many others on this site.  It is a truly awesome thing we have here.

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations to [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott), who reached 300K reputation as second user today! Also, it turns out it is exactly four years since he posted his first answer. My guess is that he planned on this.

Thank you for your great work for the community!

Comment: and recently the first to 500k.

Answer (score 17):

Congratulations to [Georges Elencwajg](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3217/georges-elencwajg) for surpassing 100,000 reputation on this final day of 2016!  Georges's answers in algebra and geometry are an amazing resource for a multitude of users.  His cordial and inviting demeanor makes even the most technical of his posts a pleasure to read.

Félicitations, et bonne année 2017!

Comment: Merci, SpamIAm, et tous mes voeux de bonheur à vous, à ceux que vous aimez et à ceux qui vous aiment.

Comment: For obvious reasons it isn't I who upvoted :-)

Comment: @GeorgesElancwajg I certainly did! Here's to the next 100,000 internet points' worth of wisdom, cheers! :)

Answer (score 15):

Congratulations, [rschwieb](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29335/rschwieb), on reaching 100k reputation points!

*Keep up the good work!*

Comment: Hey thanks!  Seeing the site over the past 6+ years, I think we're doing a good job, and I hope I can continue to help make the community a great place.

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations to [Mark Viola](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/218419/mark-viola), the artist formerly known as Dr.MV, for reaching 100,000 reputation!

I think I speak for many here when I say that we admire his tireless and constant striving to "provide the best answer [he] can" (as his frequent comment on his own answers says). Even now, over two years after joining, he is consistently a top contributor, and I think it is only right that we acknowledge explicitly the considerable contribution he has made to this community already, and, we may selfishly hope, for a long time to come.

In the words of Geoffrey Boycott, now 'e's got an undred he's got te knuckle down fer a really big score!

Comment: Congrats Mark!!

Comment: Hey Mark, also congrats from my side! You are one of the best here on mse!

Comment: I am late to the party and quite ashamed of that, but Chappers' words do the job nicely. I agree with tired, too: Mark is simply great.

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations to [Eric Wofsey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/86856/eric-wofsey) for reaching 100K!

Eric, thank you so much for all of your awesome proofs and counterexamples. Seeing a comment by Eric on a tough (imho) topology problem lets me go to sleep easier knowing the problem is in good hands.

Answer (score 13):

Congratulations to [Olivier Oloa](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118798/olivier-oloa) for reaching **100K**. I share many interests with Olivier and I learned very much from his always elegant and inspiring solutions. I wish him a pleasant stay and to reach many other glorious achievements, for the benefit of our whole community.

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations, [Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy) for topping $100K$ on 2/11/2015! Passing $100K$ in one's journey at MSE is a significant achievement that shouldn't ever be minimized.

You've been a steadfast contributor at MSE: thank you for your countless answers AND thank you for all the time you spend editing and improving both questions and answers.

Comment: His efforts related to editing [got mentioned in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18561177#18561177) when he reached 10k edits last november; now already at more than 11k.

Comment: Thank you.  (I hadn't known this posting was here or that this thread exists until a moment ago.) ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations to [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici) who topped $100K$ yesterday!

You have been supplying wonderful answers over here, so congrats on all the hard work taken to build these reputation points and may you continue to give good answers, sir!

Comment: My warm congratulations Claude for your first 100K! Wishing you a very pleasant end of year and continuation here. All the best,

Comment: I do not want to make one more redundant post, so I'll mention at least in comments that also [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) reached 100k [this month](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17403/2017/12/18).

Comment: @Claude Congratulations! Knowing your profile, let me tell you that you are, among other things, a model of courage for many of us.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I don’t see the harm in redundancy in this thread — Jyrki has been an excellent moderator and contributor, IMO. Plus it seems ideal that comments to this answer should really be focused on Claude (by whom I have also been very impressed!)

Comment: @pjs36 Feel free to post a separate answer for Jyrki. (If you feel like it, you can also mention that it has been three years [since he became a mod](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/17403/2017/12/23).) I tried to respect the fact that many users are against posting congratulatory posts on meta - but since these two users reached 100k almost simultaneously, I was unable to resist and posted at least a comment. (Alternatively, if you think my comment here is unsuitable, you can flag it and ask moderators to remove the comment.)

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations, to [Sami Ben Romdhane](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/63181/sami-ben-romdhane?tab=answers&sort=newest) who has topped $100$K today!

You've been a *great contributor* here at MSE, so let us take a moment to recognize your hard-earned achievement and cheer you on as you continue to do so!

*Keep up the good work, Sami!*

Comment: yeah! congratulations to one of the great contributors on M.SE ! =)

Comment: I was sad to see today that Sami's account is suspended. He's been a great contributor, as amWhy says.

Comment: I was even more sad by noticing that he left MSE soon after the suspension was revoked. Goodbye, Sami.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations [Arthur](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/15500/arthur?tab=profile), for getting into the 100k club. Not bad for someone who describes himself as an “hopeful mathematics student with some competition level problem solving experience”.

Answer (score 7):

Congratulations to [Martin R](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/42969/martin-r) for reaching 100k!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations [Pedro Tamaroff](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350/pedro-tamaroff) for getting into the 100K club.

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn) for getting into the 300K club.

Comment: It seems they have 299,997 at the moment. You may be several minutes early.

Comment: @Arctic perhaps anything at or over 299,500 rounds up to 300K.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations [Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott) for reaching 600k!

You've been the top user for several years. I hope you keep it up!

Comment: The Greatest Of All Time  (GOAT) 

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations [epi163sqrt](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/132007/epi163sqrt) for reaching 100k!

Answer (score 2):

Congratulations to [Parcly Taxel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/357390/parcly-taxel) on reaching 100k!